# Regular expression help for InputFilter for EditText in Android

Tags: android, regex

I need to implement an input filter for limiting numeral entry in the format `1234.35`. That is, maximum four before `.` and two decimal places. I am using this [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0,4}+((\\.[0-9]{0,2})?)||(\\.)?");
```

This works, but once I enter a number in the edit text and try to edit the values before the decimal places, I can't edit them. I can only delete them.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Based upon what you said and I think it looks like you were trying to do, I would use this regular expression:

```
^(\d{0,4})(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

It matches '0-4 digits' with or without 'a decimal point and two numbers' following them. If there is a decimal point, then either one or two digits must follow it. For instance: `5`, `1234`, `1234.56`, `.2`, and `.31` are all valid and matched by the expression, but `.123`, `1234.`, `1234.567`, `12345`, and `.` are NOT matched.

Alternatively, to allow numbers ending in decimals (like `.`, `1234.`, and the like), use this modification:

```
^(\d{0,4})(\.(\d{1,2})?)?$
```